# Why does my new Rust project send executables to a previous project target/debug & target/release folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

My path for VSCode Rust projects on Ubuntu 18.04 is `~/Documents/VSCode_Projects/VSCode_Rust_Projects`.

In the VSCode_Rust_Projects folder I have two projects that work fine.

I just created a third new project in folder VSCode_Rust_Projects, and for some reason when I execute cargo build as a task within the IDE, the debug executable is sent to the previous project's target/debug folder...so no target/debug folder is generated in my current project workfolder. Why??

The task configuration is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "rust: cargo build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "check",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "rust: cargo check"
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "clean",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "none",
            "label": "rust: cargo clean"
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "run",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "label": "rust: cargo run"
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "test",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "test",
            "label": "rust: cargo test"
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "build",
            "args": [
                "--release"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "rust: cargo build --release"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm stumped!  I can't generate the target folder in my new project.

Comment: Do you have each project in their own specific folder, so something like `VSCode_Rust_Projects/proj_a` and `VSCode_Rust_Projects/proj_b`?

Comment: Yes I definitely do have projects in different folders! ; and this is why I'm stumped. (and THANK YOU! for the response)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I forgot I had set the CARGO_TARGET_DIR cargo environment variable and saved it in the .bashrc file during the previous project. Setting this causes any builds to get placed at the specified directory; commenting out the setting and doing "source ~/.bashrc" fixed everything.

Comment: Do you **need** to set `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` for your setup? I have never touched it.